Windows 11 Task Scheduler - How to stop a running powershell script task?
In Task Scheduler, how may I stop a running task sooner than 1 hour, say immediately after execution?
I've tried manually entering '1 minute', but the Task is still 'running'. Suggestions?
I'm running a powershell script via Task to unlock my vault during backup tasks.. Maybe there's a means of closing its window so the task can actually End?
Task Scheduler Settings
Here's my original PS:
$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString "111111111111" -AsPlainText -Force
    Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint "G:" -Password $SecureString

Here's my bat creator code...
function Convert-PowerShellToBatch
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        [Alias("FullName")]
        $Path
    )
 
    process
    {
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
        $newPath = [Io.Path]::ChangeExtension($Path, ".bat")
        "@echo off`npowershell.exe -NoExit -encodedCommand $encoded" | Set-Content -Path $newPath -Encoding Ascii
    }
}
 
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Scripts\vault-unlock.ps1 |
  Convert-PowerShellToBatch


How to stop a running powershell script task?
ScheduledTask | ? TaskName -eq 'TStop-On' | Stop-ScheduledTask

or
Get-ScheduledTask | Where {$_.State -eq 'Running' -and $_.TaskName -eq 'TStop-On'} | Stop-ScheduledTask

Replace TStop-On with your task name tobe closed.
To check it:
ScheduledTask
(ScheduledTask).Taskname
(Get-ScheduledTask|? State -eq 'Running').Taskname
More info:

Get-ScheduledTask
Stop-ScheduledTask


Thank you; a couple follow-up questions...

Can I place 'Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName "ScanSoftware"' in my original PS1, or how else to execute it?
Wjen I run 'Get-ScheduledTask', even though Task Scheduler shows 'Running', 'Get-ScheduledTask' shows 'Ready'... what's going on here?


perhaps you can edit the question and include your powershell script

Added. Thanks for the suggestion.

Perhaps you can try to enable stop task if it runs longer than, and the value like 1 minutes in Triggers tab.

I'm thinking the answer is that the Task isn't really still running even though indicated by such in the Task Scheduler, as  'Get-ScheduledTask' indicates 'Ready' not 'Running'. I'll check this over the next week and mark this a solution if still functioning the same. Thank you again for your input.
